# PHP Twitter Apps by OAuth Issue

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I have followed  [this guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/oauth-for-php-twitter-apps-part-1/) for PHP Twitter Apps by OAuth

Here in `test.php` the last line i.e:

```
$oauth->post(‘statuses/update’, array(‘status’ => “hello world”));
```

doesn't work.

However, in `test.php` up to the:

```
echo "Connected as @" . $credentials->screen_name;
```

line, everything works, but the last line (i.e, post) is not working.

After completing the full process,  I can’t see any tweet in the Twitter account.
I attempt the full process from the link many times carefully, but all attempts have failed thus far.

Please Help me solve me my problem if you note any potential problem areas from the information I have provided or possibly refer me to a alternative tutorial that I should consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you set your [Application setting as `READ-ONLY`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq) (look up section about read/write access).

Furthermore, you can debug it this way:

```
$result = $oauth->post('statuses/update', array('status' => "hello world"));
var_dump( $result );
```

and see the result of this `var_dump`.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. It's working now well. I'm so thankfull to u.         :)